# Which is faster (in browser rendering): Include() or Server.Execute() of an .aspx script?

Tags: asp.net, performance

I've got a small cookie-leaving aspx script.

I'm wondering if it's faster to just do it as an

or
Server.Execute (same script)

or does it not matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Server.Execute` should cause the server to cache the script bytecode once, which means, theoretically, you should realize a net performance increase as compared to simply extending a running script with `include`.

Comment: Hadn't thought of that. Good 'cause I set it to Server.Execute (just couldn't remember why :-)